# Why has eclipse highlighted lines of java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning how to write java (In Eclipse) add everything was going good until suddenly it highlighted all of my code in and i can't find how to switch it off. The code doesn't matter just

The strange Highlighting of my code in eclipse
[image: The strange Highlighting of my code in eclipse]

Comment: Pretty colorful, if you ask me :)

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Have you accidentally run a Code Coverage launch instead of a straightforward Run or Debug? Check if you have a Coverage View with contents in it. https://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a special 'code coverage' run. Eclipse is painting in red all lines that have never been executed yet, in green all lines that have, and in yellow all lines where some but not all ways through it have been covered.

See [Clearing coverage highlighting in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112561/clearing-coverage-highlighting-in-eclipse) for how to get rid of this.